# aws codebuild runtime verison not supporting latest gradle version 7

Tags: aws-codebuild

I am trying to build my java springboot cod using gradle 7 but getting this error while requires Gradle 6.8.x, 6.9.x, or 7.x. The current version is Gradle 5.6. How can i get the latest version of gradle

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without much details on the build failure. I had issues myself trying to build in CodeBuild with gradle 7 and I solved by:

- Make sure the source code pulled by CodeBuild contains the `gradle/wrapper` folder and all its contents (including the jar file).
- Check in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` have the `distributionUrl` to the gradle distribution for your project.
- Use `./gradlew build` as a command in CodeBuild.